# How to continue after achieving if statement in python

Tags: python

When the program achieve any of the if statements the program stops. How to keep it running after achieving an if statement?

```
def main():
    print("Hello i'm your new virtual messenger:")
    inside = input();
    if inside == "Hello" or "Hi" or "Hey" or "Yo":
        print("hello !")
    if inside == "Whats's your name":
        print("My name is Raito")
    if inside == "Who programmed you" or "Who made you" or "Who've made you":
        print("it's you LOL, because i think no one will use this")
    if inside =="What can you do":
        print("Right now nothing special, died waiting to be updated")
    else:
        print("I Don't know how to answer your question, i told you, im waiting to be updated")

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You appear to need a loop. Whatever tutorial you are using, keep reading it.

Comment: `if inside == "Hello" or "Hi" or "Hey" or "Yo"` is wrong. Use `if inside in ("Hello" , "Hi", "Hey", "Yo")`

Comment: if i interpreted your code correctly, you just need to add a loop to fix this, along with @Ayxan's correction

Comment: @AbhishekPatel Thank you, i will try to figure out this, but i need to use for or while loop ?

Comment: you can use either, and as you need this to keep running until the user quits, you can make it an infinite loop. i suggest using a tutorial to help you code programs like this to help you understand the code more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are looking for the while loop, so you want something like this:

```
def main():
    print("Hello I'm your new virtual messenger:")
    while True:
        inside = input();
        if inside in ["Hello","Hi","Hey","Yo"]:
            print("hello !")
        elif inside == "Whats's your name":
            print("My name is Raito")
        elif inside in ["Who programmed you","Who made you","Who've made you"]:
            print("it's you LOL, because I think no one will use this")
        elif inside == "What can you do":
            print("Right now nothing special, died waiting to be updated")
        else:
            print("I Don't know how to answer your question, I told you, I'm waiting to be updated")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

With this code you loop forever. 
If you want to exit the loop at some point, for example if you read "Exit" from the input, you can use the keyword break (which let you continue with the code after the while loop) like this:

```
elif inside == "Exit":
    break
```

This lines of code should be as the others "elif" between the "if" and the "else".